# Execute function only when all array elements are identical

Tags: javascript

I have an array with boolean values:

```
var array = [false, false, false];
```

I want to execute a function only if all the elements are `false`.

I tried this and it didn't work, because it would execute the function for every `false`:

```
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
   if(array[i] === false){
      functionA();   //This function ran at every false
   }else{
      //Do something else
   }
}
```

Comment: [Or, to actually check if all array elements are identical...](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/LsDck/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
if (array.indexOf(true) == -1) {
    functionA();
}
```

The `indexOf` function [returns the first index at which a given element can be found in the array, or -1 if it is not present.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Comment: This is not same. The code in question call functionA() each times for false. But your answer is not.

Comment: OP says "I want to execute a function only if all the elements are false."

Comment: Having no element of `true` is not quite the same as having them all `false` though.

Comment: @RobG - that's true, hopefully there's some strict typing going on :)

Comment: @RobG: If it's all boolean values, like it says in the question, then yes it is :)

Comment: @minitech not once you throw null into the mix

Comment: @BenjaminCox: null is not a boolean.

Comment: @BenjaminCox: I can't tell if you're serious... :D

Comment: True, null is not a boolean.  However, given an array that you didn't create yourself, then it could contain null values.  If they all have to be false, then [null, false, false] shouldn't trigger the function.  So, I'd probably also check for null, not just true.

Comment: @Steve—how about `[false,,,false]`. All the values are boolean false and identical (note that my solution will fail here too). ;-)

Comment: @BenjaminCox: It could also contain `15`. But the OP said "boolean values".

Comment: This works and a lot simpler than other solutions. This will be handy in the future, thanks a lot =)

Considering the array is pre-determined and there won't be null value, I think this works perfectly for my case

Comment: Not a problem.  Happy coding.

Comment: `how about [false,,,false]` AFAIK the empty values will still evaluate to false in a conditional statement.  As will `null`. (probably some loophole somewhere though, I haven't thought this through completely)

Comment: @minitech he also said in the title "execute function only when all array elements are identical" but then changed it up in the description to "only if all elements are false".  Just trying to be thorough in case his language was imprecise.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
function checkAllSameValue(array) {
  var identical = true;
  var i = 0;

  while ((i + 1) in array && identical) {
    identical = array[i] == array[++i];
  }

  return identical;
}
```

Which checks if each member is identical to the next

#### Edit

In response to ilia choly's issues with performance and lookups, here's an alternative that is as fast as a for loop, perhaps faster depending on the UA:

```
function checkAllSameValue(array) {
  var i = array.length;
  var value = array[--i];

  while (i) {
    if (arr[--i] != value) return false
  }
  return true;
}
```

Whether `==` or `===` should be used is up to the OP. None of the posted solutions deals with sparse arrays, so none are general solutions.

Comment: Identical would be `===`, but it seems like that might not be entirely what was asked. (But yeah... `checkAllSameValue(0, false, '', [])` :P)

Comment: you're looking up each value 3 times.

Comment: @minitech—good point, the OP can change the comparison if required. @iliacholy—performance is unlikely to be an issue unless there are 10,000 or so elements, which seems unlikely. Can you explain why "there's a lot wrong with this"?

Comment: @RobG aside from the non-strict comparison, and redundant lookups, the way you use `in` both takes away performance and makes it more difficult to read/understand at first glance. Normally people sacrifice performance for readability, but this solution throws both out the window.

Comment: @iliacholy—I've posted a faster version just to keep you happy. The first only looks up values twice, it looks up properties 3 times.

Answer (score 0):

Gues this will help:

```
var array = [false, false, false];
var flag = true;
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
   if(array[i]!= false){
    flag = false;
    break;
   }
}
if(flag){
  functionA();   //This function call function only once
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Steve's way is better, but if you were going to use your approach it would be

```
var allFalse = true, i;

for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if(array[i]){
        allFalse = false;
        break;
    }
}

if (allFalse) {
    functionA();
}
```

or

```
if (array.every(function(val) { return !val; })) {
    functionA();
}
```

if you want a generic function to check if all elements are the same you can do this

```
function checkAllSameValue(array) {
    var first = array[0], i;

    for (i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] !== first) return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you describe it is slightly different from the title.  If you're only trying to execute the function if they are all false, then Steve's answer is great.  Depending on where this array comes from, I would probably expand it like so, though, to be defensive about it:

```
if (array.indexOf(true) == -1 && array.indexOf(null) == -1) {
    functionA();
}
```

OTOH, if you want to run it any time they are all the same, then you'll need more complex logic.

In that case, I would probably set a flag, update it in the loop, and then do the function call after the loop.  You'll also need a variable to keep track of the previous value.  If any value doesn't match its previous value, they're not all the same, so you set the flag to false.  Then, after the loop, you check the flag and run the function if it's true.

Something like this:

```
var runFunction = true;
var previousVal = -1;
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
   if(previousVal === -1) {
      previousVal = array[i];
   }
   if(array[i] !== previousVal){
      runFunction = false;
      break;
   }
}
if (runFunction) {
   functionA();
} else {
   // Do something else
}
```

Comment: you don't need to keep updating the previous value. They're all supposed to be the same right?

Comment: @ilia-choly good point...  also could break out of the loop once you get it.  I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: also, you can set `previousVal` to the first element in the array right off the bat. Then start iterating at index 1 (`var i = 1`). So even if the array is empty and `previousVal` is `undefined`, it will never enter to loop body. That saves you from checking for `-1` in every iteration, and you're not comparing the first one with itself.